# How to pass FBGraphUser object to appDelegate

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, facebook-graph-api

I am quite new to the FB SDK and iOS development in general. I am trying to pass the FBGraphUser object to the app delegate and then use it later in another view. My app connects to FB correctly and then assigns within the logginview the FBGraphUser object to the appDelegate. Now the issue is that when i go to another view it retrieve it anymore.

Does anyone know why is not working??

my code in the loginViewController.h is

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                            user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
    // here we use helper properties of FBGraphUser to dot-through to first_name and
    // id properties of the json response from the server; alternatively we could use
    // NSDictionary methods such as objectForKey to get values from the my json object
;
    // setting the profileID property of the FBProfilePictureView instance
    // causes the control to fetch and display the profile picture for the user
    _loggedInUser = user;

        [self saveFBuserToDB];
    _appDelegate.loggedInUser = (id<FBGraphUser>) user;

   // NSLog(@"%@",_appDelegate.loggedInUser);
}
```

Until here it works like a charm. It connects to FB and it retrieves the object from the app delegate when I do the NSLOG as it should....

now... when I go into another view the user is not set anymore

createExercisePopupViewController.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "myGymAppDelegate.h"
@interface createExercisePopupViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
{
    NSArray* routineName;
}
@property (retain,nonatomic) NSArray* routineName;
@property (strong,nonatomic) myGymAppDelegate *appDelegate;
```

and the createExercisePopupViewController.h

```
#import "createExercisePopupViewController.h"

@interface createExercisePopupViewController ()
{
    NSManagedObjectContext *context;
}
@end
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    _appDelegate=(myGymAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    NSLog(@"%@",_appDelegate.loggedInUser);
}
```

**SOLUTION:**

Although the answer given by @Borinschi Ivan is valid

I found another work around which is not using anymore the app delegate for retriving the fbgraph user and using this method in all my other views. this will set in each other view the fb user graph include [self fbConnect] in viewdidload

```
- (void) fbConnect {
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) {
        [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler:
         ^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
           NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user,
           NSError *error) {
             if (!error) {
                 _loggedInUser = user;

             }
         }];
    }
}
```

Comment: There are more issues with your approach (appDelegate holding the data...) but first: is it possible that your viewDidLoad gets called before user logs into FB - therefor your NSLog writes null?

Comment: the viewDidLoad from createExercisePopupViewController.h will only get called if the user is logged in. and is in another view from the storyboard. What are the problems with my aproach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have done this with a singleton class I wrote it....

//HEADER

```
//
//  imoFacebookSingletone.h
//  PeopleInc
//
//  Created by Borinschi Ivan on 2/17/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Borinschi Ivan. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface imoFacebookSingletone : NSObject
+ (imoFacebookSingletone*)facebookUser;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userFullName;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userFirstName;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userLastName;
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString *userId;
@property (nonatomic,assign) BOOL userLoged;
- (void)logIn;
- (void)logOut;
@end
```

//IMPLEMENTATION

```
//
//  imoFacebookSingletone.m
//  PeopleInc
//
//  Created by Borinschi Ivan on 2/17/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Borinschi Ivan. All rights reserved.
//

#import "imoFacebookSingletone.h"
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@implementation imoFacebookSingletone

+ (imoFacebookSingletone*)facebookUser
{
    static imoFacebookSingletone *facebookUser = nil;
    if (!facebookUser) {  facebookUser = [[super allocWithZone:nil] init]; }
    return facebookUser;
}

+(id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone { return [self facebookUser]; }

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {  self.userLoged = NO; }
    return self;
}

- (void)logOut {
    [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
}

-(void)logIn
{
    if (!self.userLoged) {
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithReadPermissions:nil allowLoginUI:YES completionHandler: ^(FBSession *session,  FBSessionState state, NSError *error) {
            [self sessionStateChanged:session state:state error:error];
        }];
    }
    else { [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"populateUserDetails" object:self]; }
}


- (void)sessionStateChanged:(FBSession *)session
                      state:(FBSessionState) state
                      error:(NSError *)error {
    switch (state) {

        case FBSessionStateOpen: { [self populateUserDetails]; }
            break;
        case FBSessionStateClosed: { [self cleanUsser]; }
             break;
        case FBSessionStateClosedLoginFailed:
        {
            [FBSession.activeSession closeAndClearTokenInformation];
            [self cleanUsser];
        }

            break;
        default: { }
            break;
    }

    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                                  initWithTitle:@"Error"
                                  message:error.localizedDescription
                                  delegate:nil
                                  cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                  otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    }
}


- (void)populateUserDetails {
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen) { [[FBRequest requestForMe] startWithCompletionHandler: ^(FBRequestConnection *connection, NSDictionary<FBGraphUser> *user, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
                 self.userFirstName = user.first_name;
                 self.userLastName = user.last_name;
                 self.userFullName = user.name;
                 self.userId = user.id;
                 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"populateUserDetails" object:self];
        }
         }];
    }
}


- (void)cleanUsser
{
    self.userFirstName = @"";
    self.userLastName = @"";
    self.userFullName = @"";
    self.userId = @"";
    self.userLoged = NO;
}

@end
```

//EXAMPLE USE

## 1 IN APP DELEGATE .M ADD

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation
{
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
}
```

## 2 THEN IN YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER .h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "imoFacebookSingletone.h"

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<FBLoginViewDelegate>
{

}

@property (strong, nonatomic) FBRequest *pendingRequest;
@property (strong, nonatomic) imoFacebookSingletone *facebook;

@end
```

## 3 THEN YOUR VIEW CONTROLLER .m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{


    self.facebook = [[imoFacebookSingletone alloc] init];

    if (FBSession.activeSession.state == FBSessionStateCreatedTokenLoaded)
    {
        [self.facebook logIn];
    }
    else
    {

    }

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(populateUserDetails:) name:@"populateUserDetails" object:nil];
}

- (void)populateUserDetails:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    userName.text = self.facebook.userFullName;
    userPicture.profileID = self.facebook.userId;
}
```